# FlatList is rendering on ios but not android after fetching the data via the fetchAPI

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm using react native and trying to render a simple flat list based on the data I've fetched using the fetch API.

Below is the code -

```
class CategoryList extends React.Component 
{
    constructor(props) 
    {
        super(props);
        var context = this;

        this.state = {
            categories: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount()
    {
        fetch(api_config.url + api_config.routes.all_top_level_categories)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ categories: data}))
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
    }

    renderFlatListItem(data)
    {
        return(<View style={styles.item}>
            <Text>{data.item.name}</Text>
          </View>);
    }

    renderItemSeparator()
    {
        return(
            <View
                contentContainerStyle={styles.itemSeparator} />
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <FlatList contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
                    data={this.state.categories}
                    renderItem={(data) => this.renderFlatListItem(data)}
                    ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderItemSeparator}
                    keyExtractor={data => data.name}
                />
        );
    }
  }

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component
{
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
      return {
        title: 'Home',
      }
    };
    render() {
      return (
        <CategoryList />
      );
    }  
}
```

Below is the image for Android -

[image]

Below is the Image for iOS -

[image]

Any help on the topic would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you try this
componentDidMount()
    {
 setTimeout(() => {
           this.fetchfunction();
          }, 400)
    }

fetchfunction(){
fetch(api_config.url + api_config.routes.all_top_level_categories)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ categories: data}))
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
}

Comment: @Pramod Thanks for the reply but it doesn't work, tried increasing the timeout to 1000 aswell. Any particular reason for this approach?

Comment: Fetching of data is taking time. So by that time the view is rendered.
Try this fetch component in "ComponentWillMount" function.
I will try and let you know

Comment: @Pramod It was due to the ip address of android emulator pointing to localhost instead of the host's IP i.e. 10.0.2.2 for android. Silly mistake on my part.